# Loading text values from JSON via pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this file that I'm trying to read :

```
{"data": {"1547700225.3": Infinity, "1547700227.55": Infinity, "1547700229.8099997": Infinity, "1547700231.9899995": Infinity, "1547700140.05": Infinity}}
```

I can't control the format of the file (ie I have to work with what I've got) and I have a few other files that are the same format that I have already read.  Obviously the difference for this one is the "Infinity" value which is causing an error when I do this:

```
df1 = pd.read_json('filename.json').reset_index()
```

or

```
df1 = pd.read_json('filename.json')
```

The aim is to read this file and use append() to add it to the other data.

All the other files are working properly because they have a numeric value, but this one had a word which I think is causing the error.

So obviously I want to read this file, replace the Infinity with a null and if there's other numeric values there then they stay there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest to first read the file with `json.load()` from the standard library, and then convert it to a data frame:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

fname = 'yourfile.json'

with open(fname, 'r') as f:
  dat = json.load(f)

dat_df = pd.DataFrame(dat)
dat_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

## >>> print(dat_df)
##            index       data
## 0  1547700140.05        inf
## 1  1547700225.3         inf
## 2  1547700227.55        inf
## 3  1547700229.8099997   inf
## 4  1547700231.9899995   inf
```

Then you can replace the `inf`s with `NaN`s like this (for example):

```
import numpy as np
dat_df.replace(np.inf, np.nan, inplace=True)

## >>> print(dat_df)
##            index       data
## 0  1547700140.05        NaN
## 1  1547700225.3         NaN
## 2  1547700227.55        NaN
## 3  1547700229.8099997   NaN
## 4  1547700231.9899995   NaN
```

Comment: That seems to work, but I didn't mention that the first value is an epoch datetime.  When I process the other files it's automagically converted to a human readable timestamp, but using your code it doesn't do that.

Again, I think I know what has to be done, it's just that I don't know the proper terminology to search for the correct answer.

Comment: I figured out the datetime and other glitches in the file, thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in python module `json` to handle loading the file into a Python Dictionary type:

```
 import json
 with open("filename.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

At this point, data is a Python dictionary where the Infinity values are loaded as `float` types.

Next you can create a pandas `DataFrame` using the dictionary:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

pandas will load the Infinity values as `numpy.float64` types

At this point, if you'd like to convert the numeric Infinity into `na` you an do so:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.replace(np.inf, np.nan)
```

Comment: Is the "x" in json.loads a typo ?  If I use that command as is I get 'X" is not defined.  If I substitute data I get 

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict